# How long does ASP.NET impersonation last?

Tags: asp.net, iis, impersonation

In my login page, I impersonate the logged in user.  The user has an account in AD and I have `Integrated Security = true` in my connection strings.  This way, the user should have access to the database.

I impersonate using the code below in the login page

`...`
`tempWindowsIdentity = New WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate)`
`impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate()`

Will this impersonation last until the users session ends?  The application calls several other project dll's, which also call the DB, as well as a web service on another server which hits the same DB.

If not, how often do I need to call for impersonation?  Lots of DB calls are made throughout.

In other words,
I need Forms Authentication with Anonymous access enabled so that I can show my login screen, but I also need the user's AD identity to be impersonated(preferably, set only once)  throughout my application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(v=vs.71).aspx

According to the content above, impersonation lasts with the thread.  Since asp.net uses different threads for each request, you have to re-impersonate often.

Comment: -1: that's .NET 1.1 content. Please don't post it unless the question is about .NET 1.1.

Comment: You may also read through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647404.aspx. @JohnSaunders, sometimes Microsoft forgot to update excellent articles for newer .NET releases. Therefore, downvoting by this reason is not fair.

Comment: @LexLi: it took me five minutes to find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx.